# What are the differences between a liposome and simple cell membrane

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-membrane

I'm learning about chemical evolution and the transition from RNA to protocells to cells.  I understand that the [protocells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocell) have a phospholipid structure called a liposome.

I recently saw a video showing CG animations of the workings of a cell and it seemed that the cell wall was much more complex than what it seems a liposome is.

I'm looking for information about the differences between a liposome and a basic cell wall (not sure of the difference for different types of cells -
 but I guess for prokaryote since that would have been first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking on wikipedia I found:

About [liposome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liposome)

> A liposome is a spherical vesicle having at least one lipid bilayer. The liposome can be used as a vehicle for administration of nutrients and pharmaceutical drugs. Liposomes can be prepared by disrupting biological membranes (such as by sonication).
>
> Liposomes are most often composed of phospholipids, especially
>   phosphatidylcholine, but may also include other lipids, such as egg
>   phosphatidylethanolamine, so long as they are compatible with lipid
>   bilayer structure. A liposome design may employ surface ligands for
>   attaching to unhealthy tissue.

About [cell membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_membrane)

> The cell membrane (also known as the plasma membrane or cytoplasmic
>   membrane) is a biological membrane that separates the interior of all
>   cells from the outside environment.The cell membrane is selectively
>   permeable to ions and organic molecules and controls the movement of
>   substances in and out of cells. The basic function of the cell
>   membrane is to protect the cell from its surroundings.
>
> It consists of the lipid bilayer with embedded proteins. Cell
>   membranes are involved in a variety of cellular processes such as cell
>   adhesion, ion conductivity and cell signalling and serve as the
>   attachment surface for several extracellular structures, including the
>   cell wall, glycocalyx, and intracellular cytoskeleton. Cell membranes
>   can be artificially reassembled.

So the major difference seems to be the presence of "embedded proteins" inside the cell membrane.